# Proving that the number of leaves in a Full Binary Tree is greater than number of internal vertices

Tags: graph-theory

I was working on my own inductive proof and I need some feedback since I couldn't find a similar proof over Math Exchange. I've got a feeling that this proof is around where it's supposed to be but still needs to be fixed a little. Please help me tell what makes this proof fall.

Prove that in a full binary tree, the number of leaves is greater in 1 than the number of vertices of ranked $2$ (internal vertices).

Proving in induction over $N$ the number of leaves in the tree

**Base**: For $N = 1$ the proof is simple, we can see that the number of leaves $= 1$ and the number of internal vertices $= 0$, 0 + 1 = 1 thus the assumption is correct for the base case.

**Assume**: We'll assume that for $N \in \mathbb{N}$ the number of leaves is greater by one than the number of internal vertices, and prove for $N+2$ (since $N+1$ will make the tree non-full).

**Proof**: Let $T$ be a full binary tree over $N+2$ leaves. We'll arbitrary choose an internal vertice and trim it's leaves, now we have $T'$ a tree on $N$ leaves and according to the assumption we know that the number of leaves is larger by $1$ than the number of internal vertices. If we let $n'_1$ be the number of leaves in $T'$ and $n'_2$ be the number of internal vertices in $T'$ we get that $n'_1 = n'_2+1$ from the assumption. Now if we recover the trimmed leaves we get that:

$$n_1 = n'_1 - 1 + 2 = n'_1 +2$$
$$n_2 = n'_2 +1$$

And since the proportions are kept, we know that $n_1 = n_2 + 1$

$\blacksquare$

Comment: You might want to describe the choice of the vertex you trim in inductive step explicitly, though -- it needs to be one whose two children are leaves rather than an arbitrary one (whose children can be other internal vertices). Other than that, the proof looks well to me.

Comment: @Peter Košinár, don't you think that Adriano is right? I never said anything about $N$ being a power of $2$..

Comment: This depends on the meaning of **full** -- I've seen it more often used to denote the tree in which every node has either zero (= leaf) or two children (= internal node) rather than a tree of certain height in which every level contains maximum possible number of nodes. The statement you're proving is actually true for all trees of the first kind; so at worst, you might end up proving more than you were asked for :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your proof is great; good job! Here's an alternate proof where I instead induct on $h$, the height of the full binary tree. To apply the induction hypothesis, I would think about removing the root instead of removing the leaves.

---

**Base Case:** For $h = 1$, the full binary tree consists of a single root node that is also a leaf (which is not an internal vertex), so this base case works (since $1 = 0 + 1$).

**Induction Hypothesis:** Assume that our claim holds for $h$, where $h \geq 1$.

It remains to prove that our claim holds for $h+1$. We consider a full binary tree $T$ of height $h+1$ with $m$ internal vertices and $n$ leaves. Now let $T_1$ and $T_2$ be the subtrees obtained by deleting the root node of $T$, which each have height $h$. Now let $m_k$ and $n_k$ denote the internal vertices and leaves (respectively) of $T_k$ for each $k \in \{1,2\}$. Now since $h+1 \geq 2$, we know that the deleted root node was not a leaf but an internal node, so we have that:
\begin{align*}
m &= m_1 + m_2 + 1 \\
n &= n_1 + n_2
\end{align*}
But then since $T_1$ and $T_2$ both have height $h$, it follows by applying the induction hypothesis to each subtree that:
\begin{align*}
n_1 &= m_1 + 1 \\
n_2 &= m_2 + 1
\end{align*}
But then it follows that:
$$
n = n_1 + n_2 = (m_1 + 1) + (m_2 + 1) = (m_1 + m_2 + 1) + 1 = m + 1
$$
as desired. $\blacksquare$

Comment: In order to fix my proof I should prove that the number of leaves in a binary tree is of the form of $2^i$ and since that $N$ is as well a power of $2$? I really do want to use the proof which I thought about.

Comment: My mistake, I was a bit confused about the definition of "full binary tree". Your proof works, provided that you describe the "trimming step" more precisely, as described by Peter in the comments.